# GetUserAvailabilityResults shows result outside working hours in Exchange web service

Tags: c#, calendar, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

**GetUserAvailabilityResults** shows result which are outside working hours  in Exchange web service although I have set **MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay** = 0 
Also, I want to know how to get and set the **working hours**. Moreover, **results.AttendeesAvailability** returns null

```
    private static void GetSuggestedMeetingTimes(ExchangeService service)
    {
        // Create a list of attendees.
        List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
        {
            SmtpAddress = "vrr@e.edu.sa",
            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer
        });
        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
        {                
            SmtpAddress = "abc@e.edu.sa",
            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required
        });

        AvailabilityOptions meetingOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
        meetingOptions.MeetingDuration = 30;
        meetingOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
        meetingOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49;
        meetingOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good;
        meetingOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
        meetingOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 48;

        // Return a set of of suggested meeting times. 
        GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                             new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)),
                                                                                 AvailabilityData.Suggestions,
                                                                                 meetingOptions); 

      //  Console.WriteLine(results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.EndTime); 
        // Display available meeting times.
        Console.WriteLine("Availability for {0} and {1}", attendees[0].SmtpAddress, attendees[0].SmtpAddress);
        Console.WriteLine();

        //foreach (AttendeeAvailability aa in results.AttendeesAvailability)
        //{
        //    //Console.WriteLine(aa.Result.Date);
        //    Console.WriteLine(aa.CalendarEvents.Count);
        //}
        foreach (Suggestion suggestion in results.Suggestions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(suggestion.Date);
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (TimeSuggestion timeSuggestion in suggestion.TimeSuggestions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Suggested meeting time:" + timeSuggestion.MeetingTime);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Exchange the **working hours is maintained separately for each user**. Every User can have its own working hours.(Although it does not seems to be reasonable for employees in 1 organization)

GetUserAvailabilityResults was giving suggestions outside the working hours because one of the attendee's working hour was different from the other

You cannot set the working hour for a user (as far as I know) however every user can change the working hours using outlook 
[Outlook Change working hour](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Change-your-work-hours-and-days-in-Outlook-a27f261d-0681-415f-8ac1-388ab21e833f?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

You can see the working hours of each attendee using results.AttendeesAvailability

the results.AttendeesAvailability will not give null if  **AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions** instead of **AvailabilityData.Suggestions**
is used 
the following is the modified code

```
 private static void GetSuggestedMeetingTimes(ExchangeService service)
    {
        // Create a list of attendees.
        List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
        {
            SmtpAddress = "shomaail@kfupm.edu.sa",
            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required,
            ExcludeConflicts = false
        });
        attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
        {                
            SmtpAddress = "vrr@kfupm.edu.sa",
            AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required
        });

        AvailabilityOptions meetingOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
        meetingOptions.MeetingDuration = 30;
        meetingOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
        meetingOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49;
        meetingOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Excellent;
        meetingOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
        meetingOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 48;

        // Return a set of of suggested meeting times. 
        GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                             new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)),
                                                                                 AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions,
                                                                                 meetingOptions); 

      //  Console.WriteLine(results.AttendeesAvailability[0].WorkingHours.EndTime); 
        // Display available meeting times.
        Console.WriteLine("Availability for {0} and {1}", attendees[0].SmtpAddress, attendees[1].SmtpAddress);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (AttendeeAvailability aa in results.AttendeesAvailability)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=============================================");
            Console.WriteLine(aa.Result.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(aa.ViewType.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(aa.CalendarEvents.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.WorkingHours.StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.WorkingHours.EndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.WorkingHours.DaysOfTheWeek.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.WorkingHours.DaysOfTheWeek[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.WorkingHours.DaysOfTheWeek[aa.WorkingHours.DaysOfTheWeek.Count-1]);
            foreach (DayOfTheWeek dow in aa.WorkingHours.DaysOfTheWeek)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dow);
            }
        }
        foreach (Suggestion suggestion in results.Suggestions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(suggestion.Date);
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (TimeSuggestion timeSuggestion in suggestion.TimeSuggestions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Suggested meeting time:" + timeSuggestion.MeetingTime);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```